# Distinguish between 眼睛 (Yǎnjīng) eyes and 眼镜(Yǎnjìng) glasses

Tags: pronunciation

You may have know 眼睛 is eyes, and 眼镜 is glasses. They sound quite similar.
I get confused when listening to someone say "yanjing". I may not know what the speaker refers to, eyes or glasses. How do Chinese people distinguish these two?

Comment: Tones and context is needed if speakers with accents.

Answer (score 2):

In different city or province people have very different pronunciations, we call it "方言"(dialect),so I don't know the situation in other cities, I'm a beijinger,I can tell how beijingers distinguish these  two words.眼睛 the last word 睛 will be light reading, but 眼镜 the last word 镜 will be normal reading, otherwise,beijingers used to add a "er" pronunce in some specific words ,such as眼镜er,but 眼睛 has no 'er' pronunce.

Answer (score 2):

Can distinguish from its pronunciation, there're four tones in Chinese "PINYIN", the first, the second, the third and the forth. 睛 is the first tone, 镜 is the forth tone.

Answer (score 0):

**普通话** see e.g.bkrs:

眼睛 **yǎnjing**，**CL:只[zhī],双[shuāng]**
context e.g.擦亮眼睛,眼睛发花,眼睛的错觉,闭上你的眼睛,...

眼镜 **yǎnjìng CL:副[fù]**
context e.g.一副新眼镜,戴眼镜,摘下眼镜,把眼镜忘在家里,眼镜蛇,...